# HTML game engine within angular

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, angular-2+

I currently have a very very basic js script that runs something 30 times per second. This is later to be used in a game engine.

But now I'm not quite sure how I can best do that. This little script alone cost me some time to write. What could be improved here?

```
function main()
{
    var framerate = 60;
    gameWindow = $('#game-window'); // Der Canvas als JQuery Objekt
    gameWindow.height( gameWindow.closest( '.gamewindow' ).height( ) );
    gameWindow.width( gameWindow.closest( '.gamewindow' ).width( ) );
    // Die Größe des Canvas dem Gamewindow anpassen
    canvasJQ = $('#game-canvas'); // Der Canvas als JQuery Objekt
    canvasJS = canvasJQ[0]; // Der Canvas als Javascript Objekt
    ctx = canvasJS.getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.height = canvasJQ.closest('.gamewindow').height();
    ctx.canvas.width = canvasJQ.closest('.gamewindow').width();
    // Setzten des Hintergrundes
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00FFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasJQ.width(),canvasJQ.height());
    // Zeichne das canvas
    ctx.save();
    var render = function() {
        draw.render();
    }
    var update = function() {
        game.update();
    }
    var game = new Game();
    var draw = new Drawer(ctx);
    var control = new Controller();
    var engine = new Engine(framerate, render, update);
    $(document).click({param1: engine}, function(e) {
        if(e.target.id == "game-canvas")
        {
            e.data.param1.resume();
            return;
        }
        e.data.param1.stop();
    });
    engine.init();

}

class Game {
    constructor() {
    }
    update() {
        //console.log("Updating...");
    }
}

class Drawer {
    constructor(canvas) {
        this.field = canvas;
    }
    render() {
        //console.log("Rendering...");
    }
}

class Controller {
    constructor() {
    }
    startListening() {
        // Stuff to do
    }
}

class Engine {
    constructor(framerate, render, update) {
        this.framerate = framerate;
        this.render = render;
        this.update = update;
        this.isPaused = this.getPaused;

        this.frames = 0;
        this.pause = false;

        this.time_diff = 1000 / this.framerate;
    }
    init() {
        var temp = this.pause;
        this.intervalID = setInterval(this.gameloop.bind(this), this.time_diff);
        setInterval(this.framecount.bind(this), 1000);
    }
    framecount() {
        console.log(this.frames);
        this.frames = 0;
    }
    gameloop() {
        if (!this.pause) {
            this.update();
            this.render();
            this.frames ++;
        }
    }
    stop() {
        console.log("Game Paused");

        this.pause = true;     
    }
    resume() {
        console.log("Game Resumed");
        this.pause = false;
    }
    getPaused() {
        return this.pause;
    }
}

main();
```

Currently I load this script via Angular:

```
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadScript('../../assets/game/game.js')
  }

  public loadScript(url: string) {
    const body = document.body as HTMLDivElement;
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = '';
    script.src = url;
    script.async = false;
    script.defer = true;
    body.appendChild(script);
  }
}
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: No, this does not seem correct. First of all you shouldn’t use jQuery and Angular together since they both manipulate the DOM. Second, you probably shouldn’t use `loadscript` to load your application code. Instead, why don’t you just write Angular components?

Comment: @Kokodoko So I should write in the angular ts file stuff that manipulates a canvas area? Is this even possible?

Comment: Why not? As long as your canvas element can be reached from Javascript it doesn’t matter if you do it from an Angular component or with jQuery code.